# Mobiscroll javascript get 2 values to input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobiscroll

I'm trying to set 2 values from the wheels for price and price2 input elements with mobiscroll but don't know how to get this working.

Any idea how i can do this ?

```
$('#price').mobiscroll({
  theme: 'mobiscroll',
  display: 'bottom',
  maxWidth: [$(document).width() / 2, $(document).width() / 2],
  wheels: [
    [{
      keys: [100, 200, 300, 400],
      values: ["100", "200", "300", "400"]
    }, {
      keys: [100, 200, 300, 400],
      values: ["100", "200", "300", "400"]
    }]
  ],
formatResult: function(data){
        return data[0];            
    },
});
$('#price').click(function() {
  $('#price').mobiscroll('show');
});
$('#price').mobiscroll('setValue', data[0], true);
$('#price2').mobiscroll('setValue', data[1], true);
```

i have added the code to http://jsfiddle.net/95ns1c2v/3/

Comment: "Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" - there's a reason it says that. Please post the relevant parts and what you have tried.

Comment: i added the code that i have tried.